# Implementing countdown timer that works with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I have a problem that I'm stuck at, I'm trying to create a countdown timer that update itself from firebase, the timer will be shown to all users whenever a user visit my app ( I am creating a school management application,I want the timer the countdown timer to look like this 12days: 32 min : 3second to exams and let it automatically refresh so that it get new content).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create a **deadline date value** and store that date value in a **firebase databse**. When the user opens the app, you fetch the deadline value from firebase and then start a count down timer in the local app.

To get the deadline value from firebase you can use [this link.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

To create a count down timer you can use [this link.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do instead of changing the timer from Firebase is to save a timestamp into Firebase (the date you are planning to countdown from) and then query it client side and do the calculations of the days from the client.